# passing data from userControl to form when event is activated

Tags: c#, winforms

I cant figure out how to pass data with event!
Inside of form i have list of UserControls, each UserControl has ComboBox.
On SelectedValueChanged of combobox, event is called and passed to main form.

Here is my code from userControl

```
public event EventHandler SelectedStatusValueChanged;
```

```
private void cmbPromjenaStanja_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedStatusValueChanged != null)
        {
            SelectedStatusValueChanged(sender, e);
           

        }



    }
```

And here is code i use to get notified of event in main form

```
 //placed in rand function
userControlInstance.SelectedStatusValueChanged  += new EventHandler(ucNarudzba_SelectedStatusValueChanged);
```

```
private void ucNarudzba_SelectedStatusValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I don't know how to get specific data  from user control here so i can use it in form
        

       
    }
```

Sorry for code not being in english!!
Thanks for trying to help!!!

Comment: Set the `Modifiers` property of `cmbPromjenaStanja` either Public or Internal (in the Properties Window). Then, you can access it like this: `userControlInstance.cmbPromjenaStanja`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pass values through an event is to make a custom EventArgs class.

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string EditValue { get; set; }
}
```

Use this class in the event handler and set the property values before firing the event in the user control.

```
private void cmbPromjenaStanja_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedStatusValueChanged != null)
    {
        SelectedStatusValueChanged(sender, new CustomEventArgs() {.EditValue = cmbPromjenaStanja.EditValue});
    }
}
```

Then in your main form you can use `e.EditValue` to retrieve the value. You can add as many properties as you want to the custom EventArgs class to pass through more information.